# $g(z)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{zt}t^{-t} \ dt$ is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

Prove that $$g(z)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{zt}t^{-t} \ dt$$ is entire.

**Attempt**

I am thinking of showing that this integral is a limit of entire functions or use Morera's theorem. For Morera I have to show that I can switch the limits of integration in which case for any circle $C$:

$$\int_C g(z) \ dz=\int_0^{\infty} t^{-t} \int_C e^{zt} \ dz \ dt=0$$ due to $e^{zt}$ being entire and consequently $g$ would be entire. I don't know if this is gonna work though because Fubini might not apply...

Comment: Consider the sequence of functions defined by $g_M(z) = \int_0^M e^{zt} t^{-t} dt$. Show that each $g_M$ is entire and that the sequence converges uniformly on all compact sets as $M \to \infty$.

Comment: I am having trouble showing the uniform convergence. I am trying to show that $\int_M^{\infty}|e^{zt}t^{-t}| \ dt \rightarrow 0$

Comment: You can estimate $|e^{zt}t^{-t}| \le e^{t(K-\log M)}$ if $|z| \le K, t \ge M$ and then compute the resulting integral.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach is use C-R equations: $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{zt}t^{-t} \ dt=\int_0^{\infty} e^{tx-t\ln t}\cos(ty) \ dt+i\int_0^{\infty} e^{tx-t\ln t}\sin(ty)\ dt$$ Now using Leibniz rule for differentiation under integral sign you can show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied everywhere.